# soapCall doesnt return any value

Tags: php, soap

This my first soap code in PHP. 
But I dont get any result. I think there is some problems in soapCall and SoapClient.

I have three file. 
server , client and  service. 
I want to connect to server and just get students name by soap. This is so simple code but doesnt work.

```
//server.php
<?php
class server
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function getStudentsName($id_array)
    {
        return 'Mohammad';
    }
}
$params = array('uri'=>'phpsoap/server.php');
$server = new SoapServer(NULL , $params);
$server -> setClass('server');
$server -> handle();

?>

//client.php
<?php 
class client
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $params = array('location' => 'http://phpsoap.exp/server.php', 
                        'uri' => 'urn://phpsoap/server.php', 
                        'trace' => 1
                        );
        $this->instance= new SoapClient(NULL , $params);
    }

    public function getName($id_array)
    {
        $this->instance->__soapCall('getStudentsName' , $id_array);
    }
}

$client = new client;
?>

//service.php
<?php

include './client.php';

$id_array=array('id'=>'1');
echo $client->getName($id_array);
?>
```

Comment: service.php return status 200. but there is not any result. I expect the result : "Mohammad";

Comment: any answer, any help?

Comment: What does the PHP error reporting say? Any entries in the server logs?

Answer (score 0):

Method client::getName should return value from __soapCall, currently is return void, that's why you don't see anything

```
public function getName($id_array)
{
    return $this->instance->__soapCall('getStudentsName' , $id_array);
}
```